# Count on a join and union statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables  (city1, city2, city3 (etc..), and Users)

city1 table

```
id   userid   notes                    noteAdded
1    55       this is a test           2019-03-18 14:40:05.227
2    56       another test             2019-04-18 14:40:05.227
3    55       third test               2019-04-16 14:40:05.227
```

city2 table

```
id    userid    notes                    noteAdded
1     55        this is city2 notes      2019-04-18 14:40:05.227
2     57        this is another note     2019-04-17 14:40:05.227
```

city3 table

```
id    userid    notes    noteAdded
........
```

users table

```
id     username
55     bob smith
56     james brown
57     scott bean
```

I am trying to achieve the following, ordered by submit time desc

```
id    userid   username     noteadded            count
1     55       bob smith    04-18-fulldatehere   3
2     56       james brown  04-18...             1
3     57       scott bean   04-17...             1
4     55       bob smith    04-16...             3
```

I have the following

```
select userid, noteadded, username
from (
  SELECT userid, noteadded, u.username
  FROM city1 cone
  left join users on cone.userid = u.id 

  union

  SELECT userid, noteadded, u.username
  FROM city2 ctwo
  left join users u on ctwo.userid = u.id
)
as rr
order by noteadded desc;
```

This is working but as soon as I add a `COUNT(userid)` before that subcommand (the select statement between the parenthesis) I get errors stating `rr.userid` is invalid. If I remove the count, the statement works. The only reason why I added the `as rr` part is because without that I couldn't nest the subquery i.e. I couldn't do this:

```
select userid, noteadded, username
from (
  SELECT userid, noteadded, u.username
  FROM city1 cone
  left join users on cone.userid = u.id 

  union

  SELECT userid, noteadded, u.username
  FROM city2 ctwo
  left join users u on ctwo.userid = u.id
)
order by noteadded desc;
```

My goal for the SQL statement is to measure how active a user is - thus the count. Eventually I plan to limit the results and/or count by date. Say, only show me items for the past 30 days.

Comment: You need to group by any columns from the tables

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can `union` the "city" tables together and then do a `join`:

```
select u.id, u.username, count(*), max(noteadded)
from users u left join
     (select c.*
      from ((select c.* from city1) union all
            (select c.* from city2) union all
            (select c.* from city3) 
           ) c
     ) c
     on c.userid = u.id
group by u.id
```

Comment: its (sql server) not liking the parenthesis right after your last union all statement  ') c ' on line 7  .. and i cant figure out why. Also not liking the first mention of  c.*  on line 3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count, which is an aggregating function, then you also need to `group by`, and for every column you want to display you have to either aggregate it or `group by` it.

```
declare @City1 table (id int, userid int, notes varchar(128), noteAdded datetime);
declare @City2 table (id int, userid int, notes varchar(128), noteAdded datetime);
declare @User table (id int, username varchar(64));

insert into @City1 (id, userid, notes, noteAdded)
  select 1,    55,       'this is a test',           '2019-03-18 14:40:05.227' union all
  select 2,    56,       'another test',             '2019-04-18 14:40:05.227' union all
  select 3,    55,       'third test',               '2019-04-16 14:40:05.227';

insert into @City2 (id, userid, notes, noteAdded)
  select 1,    55,       'this is city2 notes',           '2019-04-18 14:40:05.227' union all
  select 2,    57,       'this is another note',          '2019-04-17 14:40:05.227';

insert into @User (id, username)
  select 55,     'bob smith' union all
  select 56,     'james brown' union all
  select 57,     'scott bean'

select userid
  , username
  , max(noteadded) noteadded /* Has to be an aggregate since we're grouping */
  , count(userid) [count]
from (
  SELECT userid, noteadded, u.username
  FROM @city1 cone
  left join @user u on cone.userid = u.id 

  union all

  SELECT userid, noteadded, u.username
  FROM @city2 ctwo
  left join @user u on ctwo.userid = u.id
)
as rr
group by UserId, username;
--order by noteadded desc; -- Can't order by a column being aggregated
```

PS: if I can encourage you to post all questions in this format i.e. creating temp tables or table variables, inserting the data, and attempting a query. Doing so makes it **much** easier for people to answer and will encourage more and faster responses.

Comment: will do - is there any easy way to generate those sample temp tables from my actual data other than typing it all out manually?

Comment: Type is out manually... but better you than someone who might answer it. It also means you have a [mcve] which is important for a good question

Comment: To create your inserts, grab your data, put it into a text editor like notepad++ and use regex find/replace to turn it into insert statements. But at least its in readable text, not an image s you are half way there @Oscalation